# Sub setting a column into multiple values in r

Tags: r

I have the following data,

```
col <- c('Data1,Data2','a,b,c','d')

df <- data.frame(col)
```

I want to split the data where the elements are more than 2 in a cell. So "a,b,c" should be split into "a,b" , "b,c" and "c,a". See attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a row identifier (`row_number()`), split the 'col' by the delimiter (`separate_rows`), grouped by 'rn', `summarise` on those groups where the number of rows is greater than 1 to get the `combn` of 'col' and `paste` them together

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(col) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(col = if(n() > 1) combn(col, 2, FUN = str_c, collapse=",") else col,
         .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#  col        
#  <chr>      
#1 Data1,Data2
#2 a,b        
#3 a,c        
#4 b,c        
#5 d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(col = list(if(str_count(col, ",")>1) combn(strsplit(col, ",")[[1]], 2, toString) else col))%>%
  unnest(col)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  col        
  <chr>      
1 Data1,Data2
2 a, b       
3 a, c       
4 b, c       
5 d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `combn`

```
data.frame(col = unlist(sapply(
    strsplit(df$col, ","),
    function(x) {
          if (length(x) == 1) {
                x
            } else {
                combn(x, 2, paste0, collapse = ",")
            }
      }
)))
```

which gives

```
          col
1 Data1,Data2
2         a,b
3         a,c
4         b,c
5           d
```